# Validate if one of two form fields is filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, field

At least one of the two fields is required, if field 1 is filled or field 2 is filled the form is sent, the required is just one of them filled. I'm trying to do this with the code below, but isn't working fine, this is working only validating like required the field 1 (text1). Thank you!

```js
var field1 = text1;
var field2 = text2;

if (text2.length) {
    if (!field1.length || !field2.length) {
        return false;
    }
} else if (!field1.length) {
    return false;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="text 1*" name="text1" class="text1" data-target="previewText1" maxlength="11">
<input type="text" placeholder="text 2" value="" name="text2" class="text2" data-target="previewText2" maxlength="11">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple case of an AND condition on each length with the not operator.

```
if (!field1.length && !field2.length) {
    return false;
}
```

So it's saying if field1 is empty AND field2 is empty then the form is invalid.

This assumes `field1` and `field2` are the string value and not the DOM elements. If they're DOM elements then you need to use `field1.value.length` and `field2.value.length`.

Comment: I'm trying to do one of them required, but this is just getting the first field filled, when i fill the second field and leave the first empty the form button is okay to send the informations.

Comment: You must have a problem with setting `field1` or `field2` because this is the correct logic. You can see a working demo here https://jsfiddle.net/3jety3kb/

Answer (score 0):

Like that :

```
var field1 = document.getElementsByClassName("text1").value;
var field2 = document.getElementsByClassName("text2").value;

// Check if one of the fields is not empty
if (field1.length || field2.length) {
        return true;
}
return false;
```